# Solve differential equation $(x^3 + y^2(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}) dx -xy (x^2+y^2)^{1/2} dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve differential equation:
> $(x^3 + y^2\sqrt {x^2+y^2}) dx -xy \sqrt {x^2+y^2} dy = 0$

I have to solve this equation but I have some problems. First I have seen that this equation is not exact, but I can't make it exact.
I'm blocked and I can't solve it.
Does anyone can help me please?

**This is what I tried:**

I have $M(x,y)= x^3 + y^2 (x^2 +y^2)^{1/2}$ and $N(x,y)= -xy(x^2 + y^2)^{1/2}$, Then I have $dM/dy (x,y)= (2x^2 + 3y^3)/(x^2 + y^2)^{1/2}$ and $dN/dx (x,y) = - (2x^2y + y^3)/(x^2 + y^2)^{1/2}$ . so the equation is not exact so I multiply by the integrating factor $u(x,y)$

Now, the equation is exact if and only if $d(uM)/dy = d(uN)/dx$ which is equal to $du/dy * M + udM/dy = du/dx * N + udN/dx $

first I assume that u is a function of x only, so I have: $du/dx= ((dM/dy - dN/dx)/N) *u$ and $(dM/dy - dN/dx)/N = (4x^2y + 4y^3)*(-xy)$ so I still have $x$ and $y$ so the function is not of $x$ only. So I tried the same I assume u is a function of $y$ only but at the end I still have $x$ and $y$

Comment: I try to multiply by u(x,y) and then I said that the question is exact if and only if the derivative of u*M (for y) is equal to the derivative of u*N (for x).

Comment: Then I assume first u is a function of x only but it doesn't work. So I tried if u is a function of y only but it still doesn't work

Comment: I upvoted the question since yu added your attempt.

Comment: thank you! Could you help me please?

Comment: You made a mistake in your multiplier. You should be getting $(M_y-N_x)/N = -\frac{4}{x}$. So $u(x) = x^{-4}$

Answer (score 1):

$$(x^3 + y^2\sqrt {x^2+y^2}) dx -xy \sqrt {x^2+y^2} dy = 0$$
$$(x^3 + y^2\sqrt {x^2+y^2}) = xyy' \sqrt {x^2+y^2}  $$
Substitute $y=tx$ and $y'=t'x+t$ the DE should be separable.
$$t'x=f(t)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$x^3dx+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\left(y^2dx-xydy\right)=0$$
$$x^3dx-xy\sqrt{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}}\left(xdy-ydx\right)$$
$$\frac{dx}{x}-\frac{y}{x}\sqrt{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}}d\left(\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2}\right)=0$$
$$\frac{dx}{x}-\frac{y}{x}\sqrt{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}}d\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=0$$Integrating
$$\ln x-\frac{\left(1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}=c$$

Comment: there might be solns for negative x